# Quotations mark syntax in Windows Batch files

Tags: batch-file

When I try to run

```
netsh -c interface ipv4 add neighbors “Wi-Fi” “192.168.1.1” “00-24-36-A0-A0-61” store=persistent
```

in a bat file, it comes out as

```
netsh -c interface ipv4 add neighbors ΓÇ£Wi-FiΓÇ¥ ΓÇ£192.168.1.1ΓÇ¥ ΓÇ£00-24-36-A0-A0-61ΓÇ¥ 
store=persistent
```

in cmd. What can I do to fix this so they show up as regular quotation marks?

note: I am just learning bat so if there is something really easy to spot that I'm completely missing, that's why.

Comment: What do you mean by "it comes out"?

Comment: That depends on the editor you're using. Use one designed for programming rather than for creating documents. I recommend notepad++

Comment: The issue is because you're using the incorrect quotation mark type. What you should be using are straight, _(dumb)_, quotes, not curly, _(smart )_ quotes. `@"%__AppDir__%netsh.exe" -c interface ipv4 add neighbors "Wi-Fi" "192.168.1.1" "00-24-36-A0-A0-61" store=persistent`

Answer (score 2):

For me, it looks like, you are using "Unicode"-Quotations copied out from Microsoft Word.
Copy them into Notepad and replace them by real Quotations '"'.

Comment: Could be using wordpad or excel or just about anything. They shouldn't need to copy and paste the correct quotes, they should just use an appropriate editor :)